# Pinescript 1m backtesting

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, back-testing, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

When trying to backtest my strategy on 1min timeframe I am only able to do so on the most recent 7 days. Is it possible to stretch this over more candles? I have even attempted to customise a time period using

```
 inDateRange = (time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021,7, 20, 0, 0)) and
 (time < timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2021, 7, 24, 0, 0))
```

but my strategy returns "None".

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: There is the limitation of bars count in TV: 5k for free, 10k for pro, 20k for premium

Comment: Thanks I understand this. I am still unable to backtest 10k bars from a previous timeline and it only allows me to backtest most recent bars. Any comment on this?

Comment: The available history is not depends from script code, i.e. each indicator/strategy will be calculated on recent 5/10/20k bars.